# How to make the compiler use the right template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Consider the following simplified version of my code.
I have a template class `A`, a template function `Fill`, and a specialization of the function to work with basic types like `int` or `char`, and another specialization to work with `A`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t C>
class A
{
public:
    A & operator=(std::string v) { 
        data[0] ='a';
        return *this; 
    }
    char data[C];
};

template<typename T> T Fill(std::string value, T default_value);

// Specialization for A<C>
template<size_t C>
A<C> Fill(std::string value, A<C> default_value) 
{
    if (value.empty())
        return default_value;
    A<C> result;
    result = value;
    return result;
}

// Specialization for int, double, char, etc
template<typename T>
T Fill(std::string value, T default_value)
{   
    if (value.empty())
        return default_value;

    T result;
    std::istringstream(value) >> result;
    return result;
}

void main()
{
    int abc = Fill(/*Get a string somehow*/"123", 0); // OK

    A<10> def;
    def = std::string("111");
    A<10> a;
    a = Fill(/*Get a string somehow*/"abc", def);     // OK
}
```

That works fine although I'm amazed that the compiler manages to match the parameter to the right template specialization.

The problem comes with some `typedef`s that ease the use of `A<x>`. Here is a simplified version:

```
typedef A<12> A12;
...
A<12> def12;
def12 = std::string("12");

A12 a12;
a12 = Fill(/*Get a string somehow*/"xyz", def12);       // Not OK !
```

The compiler does not detect that the type `A12` is actually `A<12>` and uses the wrong specialization of the function, which does not compile because istringstream cannot parse with o`perator>>` into an `A`.

How can I make it use the right template specialization ?

Comment: how is **def** declared in the second example ?

Comment: Function templates can't be partially specialized (and you're not using the specialization syntax anyway), so in your example you're actually overloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template specializations are not inferred via where you're assigning the return value to.  You'll have to explicitly instantiate the correct version:

```
a12 = Fill<A<12> >("xyz", def);
```

(or whatever it is that you need...)

Comment: Shouldn't the default parameter be enough ? I'd like to avoid specifying the type at the calling place. +1 coz it works though !

Comment: @Gabriel: In your example, the `default_value` is `def`, which is of type `A<10>`, which isn't the same as `A<12>`!  (Unless I've missed something.)

Comment: Unless the type can be deduced from `def`, which I'd think should be possible if it's the same `def` as before....

Comment: @Gabriel: Ok, in that case, I don't know what the issue is!  I'll leave my answer up for now, though...

Comment: But, if the type of `def` isn't `A<12>`, then this line won't compile, either. And if the type of `def` **is** `A<12>`, then the explicit instantiation isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef A<12> A12;
...
A12 a12;
a12 = Fill(/*Get a string somehow*/"xyz", def);       // Not OK !
```

In this example, you have not shown us the type of `def`. Assuming that it is the same as the previous example, namely `A<10>`, this will certainly fail.

In your template, the type of the second parameter must match the return type. Try this:

```
typedef A<12> A12;
...
A12 a12;
A12 def12;
a12 = Fill(/*Get a string somehow*/"xyz", def12);       // OK !
```

Answer (score 0):

> The compiler does not detect that the type A12 is actually A<12> and uses the wrong specialization of the function

Actually since you're passing `A<12> def;` in your example (mistake?), the correct *overload* (see my comment on the question) should be picked. The fact that you're assigning the result to `A12 a;` shouldn't affect overload resolution.

If you meant the opposite (passing `A12` and assigning to whatever) then this could be a compiler deficiency. This works correctly [here](http://ideone.com/eyaO7).